# Parsing repeated characters

Tags: python, parsing, lepl

I'm new to parsing (obviously). I am using [LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/) library to parse some markup language.

I have a problem with this code (I've omitted details for the sake of clarity).

```
from lepl import *

a = Literal('a')[0:,...] # 0 or more, join the result
b = Literal('b')

c = (a | b)[0:]

print c.parse("abaabaaab")
```

The last line should give me ['a','b','aa','b','aaa','b']

There is no error but it hangs (infinite recursion maybe?). Could anyone point me in the right direction?

### Edit

I could do this like this

```
from lepl import *

a = Literal('a')
b = Literal('b')

c = (a | b)[0:]

print c.parse("abaabaaab")
```

But the **a** will not be grouped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pretty sure that, in your first example, you want

```
a = Literal('a')[1:]
```

With two `[0:]` repeats in your grammar, the parser will indeed run into effectively infinite backtracking.